# How to have different resolution/resize friendly website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

If you just open [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) in Full-HD monitor and start making its width smaller and smaller, It also changes the view/layout.

Handling it with JavaScript is simple but It will add lots of code. Can we do it even with CSS Magic (Declarative)? If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **Responsive Web Design** when a website adjusts according to screen size...

You can make this kind of responsive website easily through **CSS3 Media Queries**:

[**How to write CSS Media Queries for common types of devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

**[Responsive Web Design: What It is and How to Use It](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)**

If you google for **Responsive Web Design** you will find lots more information on this topic. It's really an **amazing method** to make your website look great on all devices from small to large screens...

Answer (score 2):

You would first want to introduce yourself to Responsive Web Design (RWD).
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

You can make use of a Front-End Framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). These frameworks give you an extensive list of tools to create a site with RWD.

Or also use [CSS Media Queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) to do screen resolution detection within CSS and style accordingly.